# <xsl : if> is not working while using XLST inside java method

Tags: java, xls

Below is the XLST schema for a xml file. I want to display CALLID field in Bold here for particular CUSTORMER field. I have tried XSL:IF and choose condition but not able to transform.

```
    public StringReader getStyleSheet() {
            return new StringReader
             ("<html xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xsl:version=\"2.0\">"
             +"<body>"

             //+"<table cellspacing='0' border='1' width='100%'>"
             +"<table border='0' width='100%'>"
             +"<xsl:for-each select=\"//Table\">"
             +"  <tr bgcolor='#DDDDDD'>"
             +"  <td width='15%'><xsl:value-of select=\"ARRIVE\" /></td>"

  +"<xsl:if test=\"contains(CUSTOMER, 'dell')\">"        
          +"  <td><b><xsl:value-of select=\"CALLID\" /></b></td><td  width='40%' align='right'>"
         +"Order <input type='TEXT' size='2' maxlength='2' "
         +"name='seq{position()}' value='{position()}'/>"  
            // It took about 2 days to research this one line !!!
         +"</td></tr><tr>"
         +"  <td>Cust</td><td colspan='2'><xsl:value-of select=\"CUSTOMER\" /></td>"
         +"  </tr><tr>"
         +"  <td>Phone</td><td colspan='2'><xsl:value-of select=\"PHONE\" /> (<xsl:value-of select=\"CONTACT\" />)</td>"
         +"  </tr><tr>"
         +"  <td>Addr</td><td colspan='2'><xsl:value-of select=\"ADDRESS\" /></td>"
         +"  </tr><tr>"
         +"  <td>City</td><td colspan='2'><xsl:value-of select=\"CITY\" />"
         +" - <xsl:value-of select=\"POSTALCODE\" /></td>"
         +"  </tr><tr>"
         +"  <td>Appt</td>"
         +"  <td colspan='2'><xsl:value-of select=\"APPSTART\" />"
         +" - <xsl:value-of select=\"APPEND\" />"
         +" (<xsl:value-of select=\"ABSTAT\" />)</td></tr>"
         +"</xsl:if>" 
           +"</xsl:for-each>"

             +"</table>"
             +"</body>"
             +"</html>");
        }
```

This is the sample xml data;

```
CALLID>37875161</CALLID> 
  <ADDRESS>1 golden flake dr</ADDRESS> 
  <CITY>birmingham</CITY> 
  <TN>C</TN> 
  <MAP>Map</MAP> 
  <POSTALCODE>35205</POSTALCODE> 
  <STATE>AL</STATE> 
  <EZ>35203</EZ> 
  <ES>AL</ES> 
  <EC>Birmingham</EC> 
  <EA>1300 27th Place</EA> 
  <TPC>-86.819738;33.503489</TPC> 
  <EPC>-86.8085;33.5195</EPC> 
  <APPSTART>09/07 09:00am</APPSTART> 
  <APPEND>01:00pm</APPEND> 
  <ABSTAT>C</ABSTAT> 
  <CONTACT>jeff ross</CONTACT> 
  <PHONE>205 458 7322</PHONE> 
  <CUSTOMER>dell/golden flake</CUSTOMER>
```

[attached is the screen shot of the display page. the 8 digit number is there we call that CALLID that should be in bold character if the Cust field value is dell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7XRO.png)

Comment: Your title suggests you want to know how to make use of XSLT in Java.  Is that what you’re asking, or are you asking help with the contents of your actual XSLT?

Comment: @VGR - I am asking for help with the contents.

Comment: @VGR- Can you help in this, I have tried almost everything but nothing is working here. I have to check here If Customer is dell than display the CALLID field in BOLD if not dell customer than CALLID should be get display in normal.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample of the data you are attempting to transform.

Comment: @VGR- I have edited the question.

Comment: and your xml has an  element named Table? It is still not clear what isn't working. Just create an [mcve]

Comment: @rene- actually this is working fine till I dont use this +"<xsl:if test=\"contains(CUSTOMER, 'dell')\">"  code. I am not getting why xsl:if is not working.